# ASP. NET Session variable expires much faster

Tags: asp.net, session

I set a session variable at login:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["user_key"] = res; //being some string eg: "asd"
    HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout = 60;
```

Just in case i also have

```
    <system.web>
<sessionState timeout="60"></sessionState>
```

Then i need to check for the user and get some date for their ID on pretty much every page and on every Page_load:

```
if(HttpContext.Current.Session["user_key"]!= null)
{
   sesvar = (string)(context.Session["user_key"]);
}
else 
{
   HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/login/");
}
```

**This works for the most part. But it is definitely not 60mins. I'd get "kicked" (redirected to login) every now and then and can't figure out why.**

Also the project is worked on and maintained trough Dreamweaver. Being a WebSite it is not compiled in any way and is live on IIS Server.

Comment: Take a look at: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113287/Why-Session-Timeout-is-not-working-for-your-websit

Comment: when changes occur in your server side code then session destroys automatically.

Comment: " I'd get "kicked" (redirected to login)..." - if you're using Forms Authentication, be aware that the Forms Authentication cookie is completely independent of the Session cookie.

Comment: It should be what @Jamie talks about. Also it just occurred to me that i never re-set it anywhere. I never go back to the login so it's set only once and after 20 mins of whatever in the website I'd get kicked. Thanks for the Help. Jamie If you can make your comment an answer, i'd love to click the tick :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a function in our Database ruining every hour which "cleaned" the login table, where it shouldn't have.